# rewriteCond REQUEST_FILENAME does not work

Tags: .htaccess

My .htaccess is so simple and it is already working fine in another server, but I have problem with my 1and1 server. if I call a pdf file from my server, both RewriteCond is not working at all.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?load=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not working how ?? Whats the error you get ?

Comment: The file get passed to index.php ?

Comment: if I call a pdf file, it is not loading, just pass to index.php?load=..
Yes, the file passed to index.php

Comment: What is the full URL you've tried and what is the actual path of `pdf` file?

Comment: http://www.mydomain/dir1/myfile.pdf just run my script at index.php

Comment: Are you sure that file is actually there?

Comment: Yes, if I delete `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?load=$1 [QSA,L]` it will open

Comment: Where is your .htaccess file locate?

Comment: in my httpdocs inside index.php @PanamaJack